# How to migrate work items from VSTS to TFS 2015 on premise?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

I have a team project previously created on VSTS i.e. TFS online and it has some work items created, now I have on premise setup of TFS 2015. I want to migrate all those work items into my on premise TFS 2015.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to achieve this, it's based on your requirement and situation:

- If you don't mind **losing work item history**, you could  just pull over work items,  **using Excel**. Details steps please  refer this blog- 
  -[Migrating TFS Work Items to a new Team Project using Excel
  (TFS/VSO/VSTS)](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2016/05/20/Migrating-work-items-to-VSTS-with-custom-fields-using-TFS-Integration-Platform)
- If you have **no work item customisation**, then [OpsHub](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) is also an
  option.
- If you **have work item customisation** and need keeping histroy ,
  then you are going to have to use [TFS Integration Platform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Willy-PSchaub.TeamFoundationServerIntegrationToolsMarch2012Relea).